# The "canonical fibration" for the Lie group $G_2$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, lie-groups

$\DeclareMathOperator\SO{SO}$At the very begining of [Akbulut and Kalafat - Algebraic topology of $G_2$ manifolds](https://arxiv.org/abs/1308.2263v2), the authors stated that there is a "canonical fibration" for $G_2$ of the form
$$G_2\to \SO(7)\to \mathbb{R}P^7,$$
where the map $G_2\to \SO(7)$ is obtained by regarding $G_2$ as the automorphisms of the imaginary octonions, which, as a real vector space, is of dimension $7$.

So, how does one construct a homotopy equivalence $\SO(7)/G_2\to\mathbb{R}P^7$?

Comment: The (real) spinor representation of $\operatorname{SO}(7) $ has dimension 8, hence defines a transitive action of $\operatorname{SO}(7) $ on $\mathbb{RP}^7$; the stabilizer of a point is $\cong G_2$.

Comment: Clearly abx is right. Robert Bryant wrote some Remarks on Spinors in Low Dimension, which explains how you see the stabilizer being $G_2$.

Comment: You can find the remarks here: https://arxiv.org/abs/2011.05568

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In *Spinors and Calibrations* by F. Reese Harvey, you can find proof (p. 283) of $S^7 \simeq Spin(7)/G_2.$ It takes the same approach as Bryant's notes mentioned in the comments but it is much more detailed in this case.

The main idea is to write down the spinor representation of $Spin(7)$ using octonionic multiplication. It takes some work to see that the stabilizer of a point is then isomorphic to the automorphism group of the octonions, which is the compact Lie group $G_2.$

Comment: And this is a diffeomorphism, right?

Comment: Yes. The spin group acts transitively on the sphere and the stabilizer subgroup is the compact Lie group $G_2$. The action is given explicitly in terms of octonionic  multiplication whose automorphism group is $G_2$.

Comment: Thanks, just checking as the OP was merely expecting a homotopy equivalence, and I thought it should be much stronger.